# How to collect "td" text from list of lists and add them into the dictionary python beautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, beautifulsoup

Here I am trying to get the value of every column in the table shown in the picture (for three different pages) and store them in pandas dataframe. I have collected the data and now I have a list of lists, but when I try to add them to a dictionary I get empty dictionary. can anyone help me what I'm doing wrong or suggest an alternative way to create 3 dataframes, one for each table?
[image]

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_list = ['https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/ethereum/historical_data/usd?start_date=2021-08-06&end_date=2021-09-05#panel',
            'https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/cardano/historical_data/usd?start_date=2021-08-06&end_date=2021-09-05#panel',
           'https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/chainlink/historical_data/usd?start_date=2021-08-06&end_date=2021-09-05#panel']
   
results = []


for url in url_list:
    response = requests.get(url)
    src = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text , 'html.parser')
    results.append(soup.find_all( "td",class_= "text-center"))
    
collected_data = dict()    

for result in results:
    for r in result:
        datas = r.find_all("td", title=True)

    for data in datas:
        collected_data.setdefault(data.text)
        
collected_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happens?

In your first `for loop` your are only append the result set of `soup.find_all( "td",class_= "text-center")` to `results`.

So you wont find what you are looking for with `datas = r.find_all("td", title=True)`

Note also, that the column headers are not placed in `<td>` but in `<th>`.

#### How to fix?

You could select more specific, all `<tr>` in `<tbody>` to iterate over:

```
for row in soup.select('tbody tr'):
```

While iterating  select the `<th>` and `<td>` and `zip()` it to `dict()` with the list of column headers:

```
            data.append(
                dict(zip([x.text for x in soup.select('thead th')], [x.text.strip() for x in row.select('th,td')]))
            )
```

#### Example

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_list = ['https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/ethereum/historical_data/usd?start_date=2021-08-06&end_date=2021-09-05#panel',
            'https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/cardano/historical_data/usd?start_date=2021-08-06&end_date=2021-09-05#panel',
           'https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/chainlink/historical_data/usd?start_date=2021-08-06&end_date=2021-09-05#panel']

data = []

for url in url_list:
    response = requests.get(url)
    src = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text , 'html.parser')
    
    for row in soup.select('tbody tr'):
        
        data.append(
            dict(zip([x.text for x in soup.select('thead th')], [x.text.strip() for x in row.select('th,td')]))
        )
        
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Output

| Date | Market Cap | Volume | Open | Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-05 | $456,929,768,632 | $24,002,848,309 | $3,894.94 | N/A |
| 2021-09-04 | $462,019,852,288 | $30,463,347,266 | $3,936.16 | $3,894.94 |
| 2021-09-03 | $444,936,758,975 | $28,115,776,510 | $3,793.30 | $3,936.16 |

### EDIT

To get a data frame per url you can change the code to the following - It will append the frames to a list, so that you can iterat over to do things.

**Note** *This is based on your comment and if it fits, okay. I would suggest to store the coin provider also as column, so you would be able to filter, group by, ... over all providers - But that should be asked in a new question, if matters.*

```
dfList = []

for url in url_list:
    response = requests.get(url)
    src = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text , 'html.parser')
    
    data = []
    coin = url.split("/")[5].upper()
    for row in soup.select('tbody tr'):
        
        data.append(
            dict(zip([f'{x.text}_{coin}' for x in soup.select('thead th')], [x.text.strip() for x in row.select('th,td')]))
        )
    # if you like to save directly as csv... change next line to -> pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv(f'{coin}.csv')
    dfList.append(pd.DataFrame(data))
```

#### Output

Select data frame by list index for example `dfList[0]`

| Date_ETHEREUM | Market Cap_ETHEREUM | Volume_ETHEREUM | Open_ETHEREUM | Close_ETHEREUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-05 | $456,929,768,632 | $24,002,848,309 | $3,894.94 | N/A |
| 2021-09-04 | $462,019,852,288 | $30,463,347,266 | $3,936.16 | $3,894.94 |

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is perfect but I was looking to create 3 tables with columns of the format 'Market Cap_CURRENCYX',
'Volume_CURRENCYX', 'Open_CURRENCYX', 'Close_CURRENCYX', 'Market
Cap_CURRENCYY', 'Volume_CURRENCYY', 'Open_CURRENCYY',
'Close_CURRENCYY', ... for each.

Comment: Could you by any chance guide me on that too?